# Why git pull rebase does not update my local folder?

Tags: ios, git, directory, version-control, git-pull

**Why git pull rebase does not update my local folder?**

I have below groups in one of my Git version controlled iOS projects,

```
-- App
-- Libs
```

I see, for my project in Xcode, group name and physical folder name for `Libs` folder is same (*i.e. CamelCased*) but for all other team mates, the group shows CamelCased where their physical folder name is showing divergent (*smallcase, `libs`*). I have done `git pull --rebase` and got the latest of remote repository. But still the folder name does not get updated.

Inside `Libs` folder we have some library and surprisingly app is building fine for all members including me.

Why Git cannot detect the divergence between local physical folder and remote origin folder name? What should I need to do to make my local code exactly same as origin? Note that, when I clone the project in a new location, I see the folder name is small cased `libs`.

`git prune` did not help as well.

Comment: Are you working on Windows or any other case-insensitive system? If a repository could be checked out on such system, it's better not to use letter-case to distinguish one path from another.

Comment: Me and my team all are working on Mac.

Comment: As I know, Mac could be case-sensitive or case-insensitive. Can you create two files/folders in the same folder, whose names are only different in letter case? `mkdir foo; mkdir FOO`. If it fails to create `FOO`, it should be case-insensitive. Besides, use `git ls-tree -r HEAD` to see the actual path committed in the commit.

Comment: @ElpieKay My Mac is case insensitive, I failed to create with `mkdir FOO` command. That means I can use all the paths irrespective of case in my project? interesting..

Comment: On a case-sensitive system like Ubuntu, `foo` and `FOO` can exist at the same time. One can commit both on Ubuntu, but it will cause problems when the repository is checked out on Windows or your Mac. One of the problems could be that Git keeps complaining that `foo` is changed while you are sure that the repository is newly cloned and you haven't changed anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems git don't change case only changes.

- If you want `libs` you can rename your local folder safely
- if you want your team has `Libs` make a commit with the folder renamed `_Libs` and another one next after, with the folder renamed `Libs`.

Comment: Interesting to know git does not detect it, really! any reference?

Comment: On Mac, I have observed this issue.